# google visualization api pie chart percents wrong position

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I'm stuck at google visualization api pie chart. Percent labels are mis-aligned a bit
Here is options

```
coreData = {
  options: {
    width: '550',
    height: '400',
    chartArea: {
          height: "90%",
          width: "90%"
    },
  }
};
```

And here is result :
[image]

As You can see there is 62 number sliced (62.7 should be)
How do i place them correct?
Also I'm using bootstrap3 and inspected css, everything seems correct and no overrides here

Comment: i've seen this happen when the chart is drawn for the first time, while the container is hidden -- is that the case here?

Comment: Figured out the trouble.
Well, this chart contains inside <li> tag, if I move out chart outside everything seems good as expected.
But, i still don't know which style was overrided.
Would be good to know which style rule may cause this issue

Comment: @WhiteHat I'll double check that. In my case this graph is hidden by default. Good idea

Comment: if that's the case and it is too difficult to wait until visible before drawing, try setting a specific height and width in chart options...

Comment: Solved! Thanks @WhiteHat . So, the chart was tryin' to draw itself while it's container had class 'hidden'. I changed the init logic and now it's drawing correct.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The draw() method should be called after the chart container is already visible(no 'hidden' class etc.)